# How do I position a node to a random point on a circle's perimeter in Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So I need to spawn game enemies from random points on the perimeter of a circle. This is the code I have so far which feels really close to working but isn't:

```
let enemy = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 5)

func enemyGenerator() {

//takes an x value and calculates the corresponding y coordinate on the circle.
    func enemyYSpawnPosition(x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(104006.25 - (x * x))
    }

//randomly selects an x value from a range of acceptable values.
    func enemyXSpawnPosition() -> CGFloat {
        func randRange (lower: Int , upper: Int) -> Int {
            return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
        }
        var xValue = randRange(-2.5, 322.5)
        return CGFloat (xValue)
    }

//used to randomly decide whether the y value will be subtracted or added.
    func coinFlip (lower: Int, upper: Int) -> Int {
        return lower + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(upper - lower + 1)))
    }
    var randResult = coinFlip(1, 2)

//positions the enemy using the functions above.
    if randResult == 1 {
        self.enemy.position = CGPointMake(enemyXSpawnPosition(), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + enemyYSpawnPosition(enemyXSpawnPosition()))
    }
    else {
        self.enemy.position = CGPointMake(enemyXSpawnPosition(), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - enemyYSpawnPosition(enemyXSpawnPosition()))
    }
}
```

The issue is that when positioning the enemy I must call the enemyXSpawnPosition function twice and when I do that I get two different values. When I'm laying out the positions I need the values to stay the same.

Is there an easier way to randomly position a node on a circle's perimeter or is their a way to fix what I've already got?

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier if you used polar coordinates?

Comment: That seems like a helpful suggestion from what I've read. I don't know how to use polar coordinates though. Could you direct me somewhere that could help me learn or could you demonstrate their use yourself? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This method returns a random point on a circle given the circle's radius and center position.

```
func randomPointOnCircle(radius:Float, center:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    // Random angle in [0, 2*pi]
    let theta = Float(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max))/Float(UInt32.max-1) * Float.pi * 2.0
    // Convert polar to cartesian
    let x = radius * cos(theta)
    let y = radius * sin(theta)
    return CGPointMake(CGFloat(x)+center.x,CGFloat(y)+center.y)
}
```